# Why is this JS not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added java script which , adds an extra field when clicked on + sign,
But I am really confused because this javascript is not working at all, its as if the JS is not working on the page at all.

```
<!doctype html>    <html>
       <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

        <script>document.cookie='resolution='+Math.max(screen.width,screen.height)+'; path=/';            </script> <!-- JS libs --> <script src="../js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script> <script src="../js/libs/respond.min.js"></script> <script src="../js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>     

<!-- scripts --> <script src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script> <script src="../js/hoverIntent.js"></script> <script src="../js/general.js"></script> <!-- sliders --> <script src="../js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script> <!-- range sliders --> <script src="../js/jquery.slider.bundle.js"></script> <script src="../js/jquery.slider.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jslider.css"> <!-- custom input --> <link href="../css/customInput.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="../js/jquery.customInput.js"></script> <!-- datepicker --> <link href="../css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
        $("#add").click(function() {            alert("hey");
         $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
          return false;
        });
    </script> </head>

<body>

 <a id="add">add</a></td>   <table id="mytable" width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="person">
      <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>   </table> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: The code that would "add" your field is commented out. I don't know what your HTML looks like, and it looks like you've got a fair amount of script missing, so I can't help you much more beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple...the elements don't exist when you run the code and you haven't wrapped code in `ready` handler that waits for all html to exist before running

```
$(function(){

  /* your code*/
})
```

[**ready() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Conversely, if your script was just before closing body tag it would work as is, since elements would exist before it fires

Comment: Adding script files to the end of `body` is a good practice too.